# In $\Bbb Z_{2014}[X]$ , prove that $f(x) = x^2-14$ can't be written as $f(x)=(ax+b)(cx+d)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I tried to prove this with contradiction.

So I assume that $f(x)=(ax+b)(cx+d)$, then $f(x)$ has root since $f(-b/a)=f(-d/c)=0$.

Let $p$ be root of $f(x)$, then $p^2-14=0$ in $\Bbb Z_{2014}$, that is $p^2=14 \mod{2014}$.

and from now on, I can't proceed, I think I should use some theorem in Number theory like Legendre.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to be careful since $2014$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2-14=(ax+b)(cx+d)$, then
$$
ac=1,
\quad
ad+bc=0,
\quad
bd=-14
$$
These imply that $(ad)^2 = 14$, but $14$ is not a square mod $2014$.

Indeed, $14$ is not a square mod $19$, which is a divisor of $2014$.

Comment: Why a vote to delete? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but by the way since $ac = 1$ they are units in $\mathbb{Z}_{2014}$ and we may safely say that $-b/a$ is a root.

Comment: It is usually pointless to worry about a random downvote. The vote to delete OTOH is unusual. I am actually tempted to vote to delete and then immediately vote to undelete just to learn who the delete-voter is. But, that would amount to what some call "utterly abysmal egregious ... extreme abuse of moderator powers", so I won't.